# Why do I receive the wrong object when asking for a service

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

I am defining a new authentication provider and I needed access to the password encoder factory, so I defined my provider as a service and asked for the encoder to be injected. Here is my service definition:

```
services:
    wsse.security.authentication.provider:
        class:  Fdi\CliperestBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider
        arguments: [@security.encoder_factory,'', %kernel.cache_dir%/security/nonces]
```

So I was expecting that my provider constructor would get an object of type `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory`. But I am getting a `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\ChainUserProvider` instead!!

Does anyone know why I am getting this object and what can I do to get the EncoderFactory instead? BTW, I am using FOSUserBundle, don´t know if it has anything to do with this

Comment: This might give you a clue: security.encoder_factory.generic

Comment: where are you defining your service?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer. Since this service is defined as an authentication provider, the first argument to the constructor has to be and user provider which is inserted by the security component. Changing the order of the arguments did the trick:

```
services:
    wsse.security.authentication.provider:
        class:  Fdi\CliperestBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider
        arguments: ['', %kernel.cache_dir%/security/nonces, @security.encoder_factory]
```